# Java method parameter for creating new object of different class

Tags: java

I have searched high and low for a solution to this problem, and finally signed up here to see if someone can point me to what is undoubtedly a really simple solution that is evading me.  I'm working on MIT's OpenCourse to teach myself Java and am stumped on this problem.

I have two classes, **Library** and **Book**.  The program keeps track of books created for each library, their location, and whether or not they are checked out.  I am given the **main** method for **Library** that cannot be edited.  Instead its methods must be built to produce the desired output.  The issue I am having is determining the argument syntax to pass to a method in **Library** that creates a new **Book** in the **main** method of **Library**.

Relevant Library Code:

```
package mitPractice;

public class Library {
    String library_address;
    static String library_hours = "Libraries are open daily from 9AM to 5PM";
    Book[] catalog;

    //List of Methods for Libraries
    public Library(String address) {
    library_address = address;
    }

    public static void printOpeningHours() {
        System.out.println(library_hours);
    }

    public void addBook(/*unsure what parameter to add here*/) {
            catalog[ (catalog.length + 1)] = //unknown parameter

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create two libraries
        Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St.");
        Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St.");

        //Add four books ***This block of code is the problem and is uneditable
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Game of Thrones"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Rama"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Understanding Space"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Way of the Clans"));
```

So my question is how to make the method compatible with the code given in the **main** method?  I have attempted numerous combinations for arguments to pass to addBook() and none seem to deliver.

Book code:

```
package mitPractice;

public class Book {

    Boolean isCheckedOut = false;
    String book_title;

    public Book(String title) {
        book_title = title;
    }

    public void Borrow() {
        isCheckedOut = true;
    }

    public void Return() {
        isCheckedOut = false;
    }

    public boolean isBorrowed() {
        if (isCheckedOut == true) {
        return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return book_title;
    }

    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book example = new Book("A Game of Thrones");
        System.out.println("Title: " + example.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Borrowed?: " + example.isBorrowed());
        example.Borrow();
        System.out.println("Borrowed?: " + example.isBorrowed());
        example.Return();
        System.out.println("Borrowed?: " + example.isBorrowed());

    }*/

 }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? addBook needs a Book.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what those lines are doing. Imagine that as first calling the Book constructor and then passing the created instance to the method.

Comment: @DaveNewton I suspect that assigning something to a comment probably bothers the compiler a little bit ...

Comment: @ajb Whereas I suspect the comment is a placeholder with the OPs question explained in it.

Comment: By the way, you will need more work with how you handle the `catalog`.    To use an array, you have to use `new Book[n]` where you need to know the size of the array when you do this.  You may want to look into [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the parameter to be of type Book:

```
public void addBook(Book newBook) {
    catalog[(catalog.length + 1)] = newBook;
}
```

This will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` though, because you're trying to put an element in the array after the last index.  You'll need to keep track of how many books have been added and rebuild your array when it gets full. Like this:

```
private int numberOfBooks = 0;
public void addBook(Book newBook) {
    numberOfBooks++;
    if(numberOfBooks >= catalog.length) {
        // Rebuild array
        Book[] copy = new Book[catalog.length * 2]
        for(int i=0; i<catalog.length; i++){
            copy[i] = catalog[i];
        }
        catalog = copy;
    }
    catalog[numberOfBooks] = newBook;
}
```

Or use a collection like `java.util.ArrayList`.

So instead of having this line:

```
Book[] catalog;
```

You might have

```
ArrayList<Book> catalog = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

This creates an `ArrayList` which is a Java implementation of a dynamically sized array.

Then your `addBook` method might look like this:

```
public void addBook(Book newBook) {
    catalog.add(newBook);
}
```

In order to use `ArrayList` you'll need to include this line at the beginning of the file, after the `package mitPractice;` line:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: Not rebuild it every time he adds something but when it gets full (he can double its size when it gets full, for example).

Comment: Since he's using catalog[ (catalog.length + 1) ] it doesn't even matter; it will always throw an exception regardless

Answer (score 0):

This always ends in array out of bounds :

```
   public void addBook(/*unsure what parameter to add here*/) {
            catalog[ (catalog.length + 1)] = //unknown parameter

    }
```

Actually, the best would be to use List :

```
public class Library {
    List<Book> catalog = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

Then you can simply do this :

```
   public void addBook(Book book) {
            catalog.add(book);

    }
```

Comment: Yes I stumbled into the OutOfBounds exception using that method.  List would be ideal, however I was attempting to avoid using List as the problem appears to want a different solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. This will add a book to a very important data structure called an ArrayList found in the util package in java. A programmer has to import this before the class statement but after any package statement. The code also uses a method from your Book API to print the title when a book is successfully added to the ArrayList. ArrayLists are favourable over Arrays because an java.util.ArrayList can expand without problems whereas an Array is a fixed size and is not so dynamic.

Check out this code I modified of the Library class that compiles and runs.

```
   package mitPractice;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {
String library_address;
static String library_hours = "Libraries are open daily from 9AM to 5PM";
ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

//List of Methods for Libraries
public Library(String address) {
library_address = address;
}

public static void printOpeningHours() {
    System.out.println(library_hours);
}

public void addBook(Book b/*unsure what parameter to add here*/) {

books.add(b); // add the book to the ArrayList
System.out.println("The book: " + b.getTitle() + " was successfully added.");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create two libraries
    Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St.");
    Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St.");

    //Add four books ***This block of code is the problem and is uneditable
    firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Game of Drones"));
    firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Raman Noodles"));
    firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Understanding Space"));
    firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Way of the Yoga Baywatch Babes"));
} // end main

 } // end Library class
```

I hope this helps some.

All the best,

user_loser

Comment: No the only code that cannot be edited in the Library class is that of the main method.  This is the assignment page that was being used: [link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-092-introduction-to-programming-in-java-january-iap-2010/assignments/MIT6_092IAP10_assn04.pdf) I am just using this for some practice.  Its not an actual course I am in so I have no professor resources.

Comment: Oh! In that case, I edited my code. Try this. A book is added and the title is printed to the console upon doing so. :)